# How are enums translated during compilation and how are the objects created

Tags: java, enums

```
enum icecream {
    vanilla(100), strawberry(20);
    int price;

    icecream(int i) {
        price = i;
    }

}
```

I am a little confused as to how the enum objects are created during compilation time

I saw some examples where they mentioned it like this

```
public enum Flavor
{
    COFFEE, VANILLA, CHOCOLATE, STRAWBERRY, RUM_RAISIN, PEACH
}
```

This gets translated into(during compilation)

```
public final class Flavor
extends java.lang.Enum
{
    public static final Flavor COFFEE = new Flavor("COFFEE", 0);
    public static final Flavor VANILLA = new Flavor("VANILLA", 1);
    // ...
}
```

Link: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.enum

But how are the objects created when I pass a value along with the name cause to me they just look like method calls. E.x. vanilla(100) here for vanilla the price is 100 but how does it actually gets created? I am not getting it at all. Please help :(

Comment: You have answered the question (in the question) quite well. So what is unclear for you? enum gets translated as you described. Is translated code unclear?

Comment: I am confused regarding this vanilla(100) ...how does this 100 value gets initialized as price as I am calling vanilla() not icecream() constructor

Comment: `public static final Flavor COFFEE = new Flavor("COFFEE", 0);`. You can see that the object is created by calling the constructor.

Comment: I am asking about the value initialization moreover I am overriding the constructor in that case what will be the flow of execution for creating the objects???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `vanilla(100), strawberry(20)` is just a java5+ notation. It gets translated during the compilation to proper object creation code:

```
public static final icecream vanilla = new icecream(100);
public static final icecream strawberry = new icecream(20);
```

BTW, java type should be CamelCased, so, `icecream` should be named `IceCream`.

Comment: thank you for answering... also what about the ordinal value won't it need to be initialized when the object is created along with the name like in public static final Flavor VANILLA = new Flavor("VANILLA", 1);

Comment: Since enum are "special" and you cannot create objects by your self java can keep track of it's values order. It will even work reasonable if you use serialization and different versions of specific enum.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line of code be "strawberry" rather than "vanilla"?  Also, as you mentioned CamelCase, shouldn't "Icecream" rather be "IceCream"?  Sorry if I'm nitpicking - just want to clarify in case others come across this post...

Answer (score 1):

Enums are read by the java compiler as constants, but ultimately, they are implemented like any other objects (that is, they are not special types, like ints/floats/arrays, but rather, a syntactic wrapper over a pure object-oriented language feature).  Thus, enums have constructors which you can override, so that your static enums have more than just a name.  This can be very useful, for example, if you want your enumerated values to have multiple fields.

For example, I may have an Animal enum, where each animal has a name, as well as a number of legs :

```
public enum Animal{
 Dog(4), Baboon(2);

 public int legs;

 private Animal(int legs) {
   legs=legs;
 }
}
```

However, in the absence of such overriding, the compiler generate default enumeration objects, which is essentially what you have pasted.

Comment: please don't use `l` as a variable name